# Could not create token: Implicit conversion of keys from strings is deprecated. Please use InMemory or LocalFileReference classes

Tags: lumen, jwt

Getting some error from JWT with Lumen:

> Could not create token: Implicit conversion of keys from strings is deprecated. Please use InMemory or LocalFileReference classes

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/2059

Any suggestion to do a quick fix, it seems a bug in new version.

Answer (score 7):

On [this thread](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/2059), two solutions has been proposed as quickfix:

### Solution 1:

> In config\jwt.php file Change 'jwt' =>
> Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class, to 'jwt' =>
> Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,
> => It works for me <3

### Solution 2:

> lcobucci/jwt:3.4 has this problem, composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3 can resolve it.

It seems to be a problem with the lastest jwt package release (3.4.0)

Comment: This solution should work for Laravel. If you need it for Lumen then create a new folder called `config` in the root of the project and create a file called `jwt.php` inside of it.

Then copy the contents from this file in there:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/1.0.0-beta.2/config/config.php

Then go to your `bootstrap\app.php` file and add this line in the Register Config Files section:
`$app->configure('jwt');`

Comment: what about passport?

Comment: Are you have any solution regarding this issue in passport?

Comment: Have you tried to `composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3` in your project dir ? It should works with passport.